# Add image uploader to cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, upload

I followed this tutorial to add a custom field to CMS pages:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

And it works very well. But I want an image uploader instead of a text field. How do I do this?

---

This is my Observer:

```
class test_CmsBanner_Model_Observer
{
    public function cmsField($observer)
    {
        //get CMS model with data
        $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');
        //get form instance
        $form = $observer->getForm();
        //create new custom fieldset 'test_content_fieldset'
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('test_content_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Custom'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));
        //add new field
        $fieldset->addField('content_custom', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'content_custom',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Banner Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Banner Image'),
            'disabled'  => false,
            //set field value
            'value'     => $model->getContentCustom()
        ));

    }
}
```

And I saw this line:

```
$fieldset->addField('content_custom', 'text', array(
```

It says `text` at the moment. What do I change it to, to create an image upload field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fieldset->addField('content_custom', 'image', array(
```

You can see all availabe form elements types inside the directory `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php`. See all availabe form element types in below screen-shot.

[image]

But I believe this is not enough. Since your form holds a file input, it is required to hold your form following attribute `enctype="mutltipart/form-data"`. Without this attribute in your form, it wont save your file inputs.

So For this, I believe you need to do this in your observer.

```
$form = $observer->getForm();
$form->setEnctype("mutltipart/form-data");
```

Comment: Well, simply changing the 'text' to 'image' worked perfectly, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so in order to make it work in my case, here what I needed to do :

First, we need to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the related form, but for me, the instruction below...

```
$form->setEnctype("multipart/form-data"); // care, there was a typo in the previous post
```

... didn't do the job in the events below :

> adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form
> adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form
> adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_design_prepare_form
> adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_meta_prepare_form

So I had to add another event observer on "adminhtml_block_html_before" :

```
<adminhtml_block_html_before>
    <observers>
        <Domain_Module_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Domain_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>addFormEnctype</method>
        </Domain_Module_Model_Observer>
    </observers>
</adminhtml_block_html_before>
```

Here is the related method "addFormEnctype" :

```
// Observer plugged on "adminhtml_block_html_before"
public function addFormEnctype($observer) {
    try {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Form){
            $form = $block->getForm();
            $form->setData('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
            $form->setUseContainer(true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

Well, that's not very sexy, but as there is no dedicated event to do this, that was a simple way to do what i need. Another way would be to override the "Mage_Cms_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Edit_Form" to rewrite the form options.

So at this point, your form should have the enctype="multipart/form-data".
Then, I had to handle images files. To do so, I needed a new observer listener / method. Here is the event :

```
<cms_page_prepare_save>
    <observers>
        <Domain_Module_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Domain_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>savePage</method>
        </Domain_Module_Model_Observer>
    </observers>
</cms_page_prepare_save>
```

And here is the related method :

```
// Observer plugged on "cms_page_prepare_save"
public function savePage($observer) {
    try {
        // Initialisations
        $model = $observer->getEvent()->getPage();
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $data = $request->getPost();
        $media_dir = 'cms_page'.DS;
        $media_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$media_dir;

        // Looping on images attributes
        $imagesAttributesNames = array('additional_img_a', 'additional_img_b', 'additional_img_c', 'additional_img_d', 'additional_img_e');
        foreach($imagesAttributesNames as $imageAttributeName) {
            $uploadedImage = $_FILES[$imageAttributeName];
            if (isset($uploadedImage['name']) && $uploadedImage['name'] != '') {
                // Upload the image
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($imageAttributeName);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $uploader->save($media_path, $uploadedImage['name']);
                // Adjusting model
                $model->setData($imageAttributeName, $media_dir.$uploadedImage['name']);
            } else {
                if($data[$imageAttributeName]['delete'] == 1) {
                    $data[$imageAttributeName] = '';
                    $model->setData($imageAttributeName, $data[$imageAttributeName]);
                } else {
                    unset($data[$imageAttributeName]);
                    $model->setData($imageAttributeName, implode($request->getPost($imageAttributeName)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

The last part could be simplified. In my case I had 5 image fields :

- additional_img_a
- additional_img_b
- additional_img_c
- additional_img_d
- additional_img_e

So I made a loop. The method overall is quite pretty simple / obvious.
You just control $_FILES, check what you have to, move files, and adjust data before it will be stored in database (path).

Hope that it could help someone :)